# Is it possible to filter heavily used header includes

Tags: filtering, doxygen, dot

Say I have huge project and in many source files there is included common header:

#include "some_common.h"

This causes that generated dot 'Include dependency graph' contains many arrows ending in one common header. For documentation purposes I do not need to see this reference. Let's say it is common knowledge in my team.

Is it possible to filter the header includes within doxygen config file? How?
To be more specific I do not want to touch the processed source code.

Comment: Did you have a look at MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile).

Comment: yes, this helps to reduce the size of graphs I set it to 3. But this is not solution to my problem.

Comment: I agree that this might not be the solution but is a step. Another possibility might be to ignore the complete file (EXCLUDE_...) but this has of course as effect that the variables etc. are not shown at all and I don't think you like this either. From your description is is also not a possibility that the file "some_common.h" would be on a separate directory that is not included in the INCLUDE_PATH and than the file is added explicitly in the INPUT. A small thought is maybe to write a small INPUT_FILTER filtering out the lines #include "some_common.h", I don't know the effect though.

Comment: I'm still interested in this, but in my case it's mostly STL and maybe system includes in general I want to filter out. You could do like others suggest and use @cond/@endcond around your include... every single time you include that file or ones like it... needless to say I'm still hoping for a real solution. There *is* a dependency there, and whether or not to display it should be up to the one making the graph.